# pgfplots: minimum size of error bars

Tags: pgfplots

I wish to present some data with extremely small error bars (think 1/1000 of the full scale). However, it seems pgfplots seems to refuse to plot error bars under a certain minimum size.

I could imagine this is intentional (as very small error bars are unlikely to be seen, hence should be avoided), but I wish to know if such a behavior can be turned off.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
    error bars/error mark options = {draw = none}
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    [
    error bars/y dir      = both,
    error bars/y explicit = true,
    ymin = -0.5,ymax = 0.5,
%   ymin = -5,ymax = 5,
%   either scale results in the same size of error bar in the pdf, about 1/30 of fullscale
%    ymin = -0.00005,ymax = 0.00005, % this however scales correctly
    ]
    \addplot[draw = none] table[y error index = 2]
    {0 0 1e-5};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Notice that the third ymin/ymax choice proves that the problem is not calculation precision with very small numbers. (Or does it?)

Answer (score 1):

In general PGFPlots seems to behave as expected as I will explain in a minute how we can "prove" that. But it seems that you found a minor bug, too.

(Please notice that I have changed your problem from `y` error bars to `x` error bars to have a less high image.)

- Step 0: Use below MWE and zoom in the resulting PDF to show the error bar.
  (Here it seems that you have found a bug, because the both additional lines at the end of the error bar shouldn't be there because of `error mark options={draw=none}`.
- Step 1: Comment the line `error mark options={draw=none}` to make this "artifact" smaller.
- Step 2: Remove a zero after the decimal sign in both `xmin` and `xmax` to "make the error bar smaller"/"zoom out of the picture".
- Step 3: Repeat Step 2 and you will see that the horizontal marks at the end error bars start overlapping
- Step 4: Repeat Step 2. Now the horizontal marks at the end of the error bar are overlapping (almost) entirely, which is, why you think that the error bar isn't further shrinking when further zooming out.

In case with activated `error mark options={draw=none}` option the not-vanished end mark is bigger and so in total stays bigger than after step 4.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        compat=1.14,
        % don't show markers
        no markers,
        % changed the style of the error bar
        % to better show what is going on
        error bars/error bar style={
            red,
            thick,
            opacity=0.25,
        },
        error bars/.cd,
            % step one: comment the next line
            error mark options={draw=none},
            x dir=both,
            x explicit=true,
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            % further steps:
            % enlarge x range by remove zeros after the decimal sign
            xmin=-0.00005,
            xmax=0.00005,
        ]
            \addplot+ [draw=none] table [x error index = 2] {
                0 0 1e-5
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the error bar after the different steps as described above]

Comment: For the record: I added the bug to the [PGFPlots Tracker](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/141/).